# install all jars in folder using maven-install-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, pom.xml

I have a folder lib in my project with some external jars. I am using maven-install-plugin to add these jars in to my local reposotory. However I need to create a seperate configuration for every jar to be installed. Is there a way by which I can copy all the jars in lib folder in to local repository.

Answer (score 2):

### Option One

If the contents of the lib directory, matches the directory structure in a maven repository, i.e:

```
/lib/{groupid1}/{groupid2}/{artifactid}/{version}/{artifactid}-{version}.jar
```

For example:

```
/lib/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
```

you can just copy the whole directory to your `~/.m2/repository` directory

```
cp -R lib/*  ~/.m2/repository
```

If not, then you have to install them one by one manually, because Maven has no way of working out what the group id is purely from the filename.

### Option Two

Another option would be to not put them into you local repository at all and instead specify a `systemPath` in your `dependency` tags in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.4</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Suppose contents of the lib directory, matches the folder structure in a maven repository is there any plugin available to do the copy

Comment: You don't sound sure :D Here is more details: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+Layout+-+Final . Maybe you could you post the contents of your lib directory?

Comment: I've also added another option into my answer that doesn't involve copying the dependencies into your local repo

Answer (score 1):

You need to give in particular the groupId, artifactId and version of those file, cause these are the Maven coordinates to distinguish the artifacts in Maven.
If you have a lib folder better start using a repository manager and install them into the repository manager once and afterwards you can use them as usual dependencies.